# LU Factorization (Non-Square Matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having a lot of trouble determining the LU factorization of this matrix. I have performed row reduction, but I can't seem to get the correct answer. If anybody can help me to understand how to complete this problem (by finding U) I would greatly appreciate it.

\begin{array}{cc}
   -3 & 1 & 2\\
   9 & -4 & -6\\
   -3 & -1 & 1\\
   0 & 2 & -3\\
  \end{array}

Rusty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
-3 & 1 & 2 \\
9 & -4 & -6 \\
-3 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & -3 
\end{array}
\right)
\stackrel{R_2 + 3R_1}{\longrightarrow}
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
-3 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
-3 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & -3 
\end{array}
\right)
\stackrel{R_3 - R_1}{\longrightarrow}
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
-3 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & -3 
\end{array}
\right)
\stackrel{R_3 - 2R_2\;\&\;R_4+2R_2}{\longrightarrow}
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
-3 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -3 
\end{array}
\right).
\end{align}

You can do the last step to obtain $U$.